# Maybe I'm not using this formula correctly?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Here is my starting formula =PRODUCT(C:D)
I would like to write this formula in such a way that it works for the entire column of D. So whatever value I enter in column D is multiplied by the value in column C. D will always be multiplied by C in the same row. (example =PRODUCT(C1:D1) AND THEN =PRODUCT(C2:D2), so on and so forth)

The values in column C are all different, if this was a constant number I would already be a happy camper, but alas it is always different.

Basically, my column B is a part number, column C is quantity, column D is price, finally a specific cell in column E is =PRODUCT(D:D)

If you can tell this is a Menards shopping list, for a home remodeling project that I'm planning. So my list will continue to grow, and numbers will change, both Quantity column and Price column.

I know what I'm trying to accomplish in my head and am having a very hard time iterating that in writing. Hopefully this makes sense to someone else here and can help me out.

Comment: So you need to multiply values from columns C and D from the same row and put them in E?

Comment: Something like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18ebe1S5nV9XzQueNbMxHMx40Qy1ErlWTmT5xfqCwImA/edit?usp=sharing ?

Comment: @CollinD _ Google Docs FTW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this in cell `E1`:

```
=C1*D1
```

And drag the formula down the column by the black square in the lower right corner of the cell.

If you want sum of products of all these cells, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:C,D:D)
```

Comment: I was actually just working on this as you posted. Thanks for the reply Taosique. I used =PRODUCT(C1*D1) and in my case it was the green square in the lower right corner of the cell. I was trying to do this without adding another column to my workbook. But this works great.

Comment: Bear in mind that the SUMPRODUCT formula given is being forced to calculate more than two million cells. Unless the OP actually has data extending all the way down to row one million-plus, that's a very inefficient formula.

Comment: No, it won't calculate all million cells and will go fast. It will accept only actually used range, even if whole columns are passed as arguments.